# Set zoom for Webview

Tags: android

I have a WebView and 2 urls to open it it. What I want to do is, when i set a zoom level for 1st url, and then i go to 2nd url, it should also have the same zoom level. Right now, the zoom level resets for both.

Thanks,
Farha

Answer (score 48):

this will be applicable in this scenario i believe

```
mWebView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL);
```

where ZOOM_LEVEL for example can be
25 for 25%
150 for 150%

Comment: The correct Answer for webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR); is deprecated

Answer (score 35):

use the [webSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) class

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Notice that although [webSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) is available since API Level 1, [WebSettings.ZoomDensity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html) is available since API Level 7. Works well for all device resolutions.

Also, in order to enable zoom on the webView, add the following code:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: It seems this is now deprecated.

Comment: it is deprecated property.. see my updated answer to over come it

Answer (score 24):

setDefaultZoom is deprecated.

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

So instead of that you can use like below,

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

This help you to remove

```
setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR).
```

Answer (score 13):

Before you leave the first page, use

```
int scale = 100 * webView.getScale();
```

Then after you load the second page, use

```
webView.setInitialScale( scale );
```

Comment: getScale(); is now deprecated.

Comment: since `getScale()` is deprecated, I used `getScaleY()` and achieved the same effect

Answer (score 4):

@John gave the right idea, but one command is enough, since you can get and set before the page shows:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.setInitialScale((int)(100*view.getScale()));
    }
}
```

then just set this as your WebView's client:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: I'm using a Marshmallow tablet and could not for the life of me get the page to scale to the size of the webview... that is until I read your post.  I used your code except for one change because `.getScale()` is deprecated: `view.setInitialScale((int)(100*view.getScaleY()));`

Answer (score 3):

You can set the zoom to 0.1f

mWebView.zoomBy(0.1f);

Comment: this is the best answer on Lollipop

Answer (score 2):

try this thing

```
int default_zoom_level=100;
Point Scroll=new Point(0,0);
webview1.setInitialScale(default_zoom_level);
    webview1.loadData("url");
```

After doing zoomIn/ZoomOut or Scrolling.Since Scale may be get to change so calculate scale level and scrolling along X and Y Axis.

```
int current_scale_level=(int)webview1.getScale()*100;
Scroll.x=webview1.getScrollX();
Scroll.y=webview1.getScrollY();

then before loading of next webview do this

webview2.setInitialScale(current_scale_level);
    webview2.loadData("url");
webview2.scrollTo(Scroll.x,Scroll.y);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but gave me idea how to fix my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog helpful:

It will help you set initial zoom level and on seek-change  content of webview resizes

// Set the initial progress of seek bar
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mWebView.getSettings().getTextZoom()/25);

```
    // Set a change listener for seek bar
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            /*
                public abstract void setTextZoom (int textZoom)
                    Sets the text zoom of the page in percent. The default is 100.

                Parameters
                    textZoom : the text zoom in percent
            */

            // Zoom the web page text
            // We will allow text zooming 25% to 300%
            mWebView.getSettings().setTextZoom(i*25);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

**http://android--code.blogspot.in/2016/01/android-how-to-change-webview-text-size.html**

Answer (score 0):

Zooming of WebView can be controlled programatically by `zoomIn()` and `zoomOut()` methods