# Android WebView Zoom out limited

Tags: android, webview

I am using a WebView in Android. After loading a webpage I would like to use the on-screen Zoom out control. After one or two clicks it becomes grayed and no longer allows me to zoom out any further. When I call the zoomOut() function in code, it also does not zoom out any further.

What is limiting how much I can zoom out. I would expect to be able to zoom out much further than I am allowed - to the point of making the page too small to read. But, zoom out is disabled well before I reach this level of zoom.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Barry.

Comment: check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview

Answer (score 20):

You should probably do this `myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)`

You'll then see that you can zoom out farther than what you usually see on default settings.

Comment: This is ugly workaround. Wide viewport is for different purpose, and sometimes not desired.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [WebView.setInitialScale(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29) - I'm not sure if it will help you with what you want but setting it to 50, for example, will scale the `WebView` to 50% of its normal size. I think that will allow you to zoom in and then out again to the (initial) smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

> Hey Barry
>            The built in range for that zoomin and zoomout function is starts from 0.8 something that is the minimum value after this if you
>   will call the zoomout function it will return the false value and
>   maximum value for zoomin is upto 4.0 ,So these zoomin and zoomout
>   functions are of boolean type Like for a zoomin function wverytime you
>   call zoomin function it multiply with some factor and return true if
>   further zoomin is possible and whenever it reaches to the last point
>   that is 4.0 so it will return false and after that it will not zoom
>   in.

Comment: webview.loadwithOverViewMode(true);