# How to set android webview zoom to specific height

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using a Webview to look at a local image with zoom support and all that. Is there any way that I can make the WebView zoom to only fit the height of the image, instead of the width like it does with my current code? Here is what I have:

```
WebView image = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    image.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    image.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    image.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    image.setLayoutParams(new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    image.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.png");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the webView Settings

use the webSettings class

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Check out [Set zoom for Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview)

*Update:*
as `setDefaultZoom` deprecated [you need to use another settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30496247/5599807)