# Problems loading a WebView in a RelativeLayout with the 50% of the width of the screen

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout (**A**) with fill parent width, and inside it, I have another relativelayout (**B**) with 50% of the size of the screen (376px).

Inside **RL B** I have a webview, that is displaying a website. The size of the view is the 50% of the screen, but the website is being displayed at fullsize, it means I can only see the half part of the website, and the other half part is not being displayed.

I want to fit the website to the view width, so I must view the 100% of the website, in a view that haves the 50% of the width of the screen

I tried using this:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(activity);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.setEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

But it doesn't works, I only see the 50% of the width of the website, and not the full website.

What is wrong in the code? Why is not working `.setLoadWithOverviewMode` ?

Comment: `RelativeLayout ` child's does not respect the height of the parent :) you need to set the height of the webview to the 50% or use `LinearLayout ` instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: i'm talking about widht, it's the same with width?

Comment: also, how can i set the width of the webview to 50%? i tryed with .setMinimumWidth() but doesn't works

Comment: ~oh..yes it is same for width :) try to fix the width of the webview

Comment: how can i set the width of the webview to 50%? i tryed with .setMinimumWidth() but doesn't works

Comment: to set width `webView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(376,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: i did it, doesn't works, i think the layout params of the webview are the relativelayout paramas of the parent or something, becase is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to fix the website content into the webview properly while loading.
You can enable pinch in and pinch out using following code `wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);`. This allows the user can to zoom in and out.
You can set the scale for webview also while loading the webpage using following code:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

For more info you can see [Set zoom for Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, please try to avoid using "txt speak", like using "i" instead of "I" and "u" instead of "you" - this will make your answers much easier to read.