# how to make available zoom in/out in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Everywhere I could find that more proper way is set

`setBuiltInZoomControls(true)`

but seems it does not work anymore, what the proper way now ? except taking it from meta-head of the page ?

this is my code

```
    mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

But i still can't use fingers to zoom in/out the page

Comment: can you post your zoom code that how to set that?

Comment: To enable the built-in zoom, set WebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean) (introduced in API level "CUPCAKE"). Please check cupcake

Comment: @sarang do you mean that I'm using old sdk ? or what ? sorry i'm not Java developer, and this is first my andoid app :)

Comment: try this: webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`mywebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29) in order to display the built in zoom controls.

Comment: thanks, you are right, but it is very strange I've tried such approach and eclipse shows me that i can't use that method because it is unavailable ;( very strange.

Comment: What is your min sdk version in the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Try using the webView Settings

use the webSettings class

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Check out [Set zoom for Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Try [setDisplayZoomControls(boolean enabled);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls%28boolean%29) in combination with [setBuiltInZoomControls (boolean enabled);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29)