# Web view content gets displayed differently on smaller Android Device

Tags: java, android, html, webview

i am facing a pretty weird issue here.

I am programming an android app, in wich the user is required to login or register. On clicking the register-button, my login - activity creates a new instance of my web view fragment, in which the web view its shown. It also sets a "back to login" - button visible. All that stuff worked perfectly fine until i tested it on another device:

[a busy cat http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/745/VplKsC.jpg](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/745/VplKsC.jpg)

So what you see on the right phone is the web view filling out the whole screen, displaying all its content (button and label are all web content, just the blue button at the bottom is native). On the left phone the web view also fills out the whole screen, but the content seems to be no bigger than a centimeter. I tried defining other attributes for the web view like "fill_parent" and "wrap_content" but it doesn't chance anything, exempt that with wrap content, the web view on the left screen scales down to the size of less than a centimeter.. Did anyone experience these issues as well? Any ideas are much appreciated because i am really stuck here...

Update 1

The Layout of the view displayed:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.mplg.sample.app.webview.WebViewFragment">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text=" Zurück zum Login "
    android:id="@+id/backToLogin"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybluebutton"/>
```

As already said, the web view fills out the whole screen on both devices. Its just the content that doesn't get displayed properly on the left screen. Could this be an issue with the web service/responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

Have tou tried to make a XML layout for smaller device ? Otherwise you can set a default zoom or let the user zoom, [Set zoom for Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview)

Comment: that won't help at all because as i said the layout is perfectly fine

Comment: try the WebSettings.ZoomDensity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html

Comment: hm thanks but that doesn't help as well - i assume it must be the web service

Comment: It turned out now that it is due to a distance unit in css, which is only supported in Android 4.3+!

Comment: to be exact it is the vh - unit that causes the problem, which is not supported in Android versions 4.3 and lower, as seen on http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units So don't use that unit for android - web services !!