# webview for zoom in layout with view type

Tags: android, performance

i cant use this code 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview)
in may app
i have this code and each Button run a activity and each activity Changing  view = "book" to a string with web view but texts show very small is tablet and biger then

```
enter code here
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toast.makeText(PoostplusActivity.this, "bueatiful skin is here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Aceneandice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Aceneandice);
    Aceneandice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PoostplusActivity.this, iceandacene.class);
            PoostplusActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    sadaf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sadaf);
    sadaf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PoostplusActivity.this, sadaf.class);
            PoostplusActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ofonat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ofonat);
    ofonat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PoostplusActivity.this, ofonat.class);
            PoostplusActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    sarsiyah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sarsiyah);
    sarsiyah.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PoostplusActivity.this, jooshsarsiyah.class);
            PoostplusActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```