# Android Webview Zoom Control

Tags: android, android-webview, pinchzoom

I want to control android webview zoom in, zoom out using seekbar just like pinchzoom. How can I do that? Webview text zooming control is given from API level 14. But I have to support it from lower API level(8).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview

Answer (score 1):

Simple, by using webView object,

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```