# How to programmatically zoom in/out browser ( not a webview )

Tags: android, android-browser, android-websettings

How to zoom in/out browser programmatically (not a webview)? Or maybe it is impossible to do that ?

For a PC I can do it by pressing Ctrl and + , but how to do it in Android?

I speak about android browsers (like a Google Chrome), not about WebView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set zoom for Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505393/set-zoom-for-webview)

Comment: I wouldn't consider using the `CTRL`+`+` [hotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_shortcut) a "programmatic" approach... unless you are trying to use said hotkey through code (which seems very unreliable).

Comment: petey, it is not a duplicate of that question, since in that question they are speaking about WebView but I mentioned a default Android browser.

Comment: Bryan, do you have any idea how to organize that zoom process ?

Comment: What do you mean by "organize"? Are you attempting to write any code? If so, post what you have.

Comment: The problem is that I have tried the following but it does not work:
     mKey = new Key(RemoteIME.mService, event.getAction(), KeyEvent.META_CTRL_ON & KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PLUS);

Comment: This is impractical.

First, you cannot control other apps, except through specific capabilities (e.g., acceessibility services) that place security and distribution limitations on your app.

Second, there are dozens, if not hundreds, of Web browsers for Android. None of them necessarily have to offer a zoom option that could be controlled through an accessibility service.

Comment: I know that Google Chrome offers that possibility, but do not have any idea how to make it true

Comment: If you are trying to make it for Chrome specifically, the `CTRL`+`+` hotkey is not recognized on Android. [From what I could find](https://www.pcworld.com/article/184656/android_keyboard_shortcuts.html), Chrome recognizes `MENU`+`I` to zoom in. Though, as I mentioned before, this seems very unreliable; not all browsers will recognize the same hotkey, and Google could decide to change this functionality in Chrome at any time.

Comment: Yes google chrome offers some customisation check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that in default android browsers as you have no control over them programatically but by using custom tabs you can achieve some customisation, check out this site:-

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: Hmmm, but I have just connected a usb keyboard to my android box and Ctrl + combination worked

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange but for zoom in/ out are responsible KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND / KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD. However, that worked for me in Google Chrome ( I have not tried in other browsers ).